# How to save background color from another acivity in android java

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to let users choose background colors with animation in BackgroundActivity and saving that changed background color into MainActivity.

When a user clicks `backgroundChange` button on MainActivity, it moves to BackgroundActivity. Then there are a few different colors to choose. After a user click Save button after choosing color on BackgroundActivity, it is going back to MainAcitivity. My problem is I don't know how to save that changed background color from BackgroundAcivity to MainAcivity.

As a beginner, I cannot understand well how to use SharedPreferences.
I checked several videos and searching many questions for hours about it, but still, I cannot figure out how to use SharedPreferences correctly on my own code.

BackgroundAcivity is really long that I will only put the first part. Could you tell me how to save this background change?

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button backgroundChange;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        backgroundChange = findViewById(R.id.backgroundChange);
        backgroundChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

***BackgroundActivity***

```
public class BackgroundActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_blue, btn_purple, btn_orange, btn_save;
    View holderBg, dynamicBg;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_background);

        btn_save = findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BackgroundActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        btn_blue = findViewById(R.id.btn_blue);
        btn_purple = findViewById(R.id.btn_purple);
        btn_orange = findViewById(R.id.btn_orange);

        holderBg = findViewById(R.id.holderBg);
        dynamicBg = findViewById(R.id.dynamicBg);

        //set the first-time background
        holderBg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_blue);
        holderBg.setScaleY(3);
        holderBg.setScaleX(3);

        //set the scale of button clicked
        btn_blue.setScaleY(1.5f);
        btn_blue.setScaleX(1.5f);

        btn_blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //scale animation
                btn_blue.animate().translationY(20).scaleX(1.5f).scaleY(1.5f).setDuration(800).start();

                //default the scale buttons
                btn_purple.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
                btn_orange.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();

                //change the background
                dynamicBg.animate().scaleX(3).scaleY(3).setDuration(800).start();
                dynamicBg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_blue);

                //change color of button
                btn_save.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3498db"));


                //timer for change the holderbg
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        holderBg.setScaleX(3);
                        holderBg.setScaleY(3);
                        holderBg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_blue);
                        dynamicBg.setScaleX(0);
                        dynamicBg.setScaleY(0);
                    }
                }, 850);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand, You want to save your current background, and use it in other activities? Am I right?

Comment: @A.R.B.N Yes. There is a button on MainActivity. If it clicks, then it goes to BackgroundActivity. Then there are options to change colors on BackgroundActivity. When user clicks Save button on BackgroundActivity, then I want to save it that changed color and go back to MainActivity and keep using that changed color.

Comment: @A.R.B.N I edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bundle to transfer your data across Activity.

- Saving data

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY, "your value here");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then to retrieve data.

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
 if (intent != null ) { //Null Checking
    String strData= intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
    // do your work with `strData`
  }
```

Comment: I am so sorry that I cannot understand how to use this code on my project. Could you explain exactly how I can use this on my code? I tried to code with it, but just don't know where to put and how to put.

Comment: You should use Saving data in BackgroundActivity in onClick method and pass the color code in intent.putExtra(KEY, "color code"); Then in MainActivity use retrieve data in OnCreate, finally, strData is your selected color code. Do the things with your color code everywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the details. Sorry to ask again.. what do you mean "Do the thing with your color code everywhere you want"? The code on BackgroundAcivity is repeating as there are five different color options. Is there some code I have to do after or inside ``dynamicBg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_blue);``?

Comment: I mean you save your color-code (for example #3498db) in a bundle or if you want save more than one color you can still use bundle with different keys, and get the keys as the color code in the main activity and use the codes to set on every view component you like,

Comment: There are five colors to choose. How to save different keys for the colors? https://github.com/bluetree007/color/tree/main I put here full codes about xml and activity

Comment: I check that and will send a pull request

Comment: Check out github